# Reveal close not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using reveal modal. In this I am getting a bug, when i close modal for the first time it closed

but if i do it again it closed but the background having class `reveal-modal-bg` its display is still block, which block the any action on page.

This happens randomly.

This is my code,

```
$("#editBillingCancelLink").on("click", function (e) {
           $("#edit_billing_popup").foundation('reveal', 'close');
           e.preventDefault();
});
```

How should i handle this??

Comment: apply coding in jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: i missed while posting, i have used it.

Comment: try triggering the event like this `$('a.close-reveal-modal').trigger('click');`

Comment: this is again happening.